# How can I add max value to a new column to each group member using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

row data

```
Ticker   date      price
  a   11/11/2017    11.1
  a   11/12/2017    12.1
  a   11/13/2017    13.1
  b   11/11/2017    3
  b   11/12/2017    4
  b   11/13/2017    2
  c   11/11/2017    100
  c   11/12/2017    87
  c   11/13/2017    104
```

I want the result to be like:

```
Ticker  max      max_date    min     min_date
  a     13.1    11/13/2017  11.1    11/11/2017
  b      4      11/12/2017   2      11/13/2017
  c     104     11/13/2017   87     11/12/2017
```

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate

```
df_new = df.groupby('Ticker').agg(['min', 'max'])
df_new.columns = df_new.columns.map('_'.join)


        date_min    date_max    price_min   price_max
Ticker              
a       11/11/2017  11/13/2017  11.1        13.1
b       11/11/2017  11/13/2017  2.0         4.0
c       11/11/2017  11/13/2017  87.0        104.0
```

Comment: There's one issue that your answer give me the max value of dates. But I want the date which represents the max value of price.